# How do I make struct store only one variable at a time? c++

Tags: c++, c++11

I understand that with a union, all members share the same memory. With a struct, they do not share memory, so a different space in memory is allocated to each member of the struct.

My solution requires me to create a struct that will only store value in one of the types stored in the struct; behave like a union. The reason why I cannot use a union is because one of the "types" specified is a string and you cannot contain a string variable in a union. How can I ensure only one member of a struct takes up space in the memory at a time?

Comment: Can you show what your struct would look like if you *didn't* have this union-like requirement?

Comment: struct S {
      T1 t1;
      T2 t2;
  };

Comment: I am using templates so the types can vary, they can be predefined or user defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I ensure only one member of a struct takes up space in the memory at a time?

You can use a `std::any`, or `std::variant`, if supported by your compiler (C++17) or you can template your type

```
template <typename T>
struct wrap
{
   T elem;
};
```

Comment: I don't see how this would allow the OP's other requirement, to have the struct behave like a union, as he wouldn't be able to allow it to stand in for other types.

Comment: If you're not on C++17 yet, you can resort to Boost.Variant or Boost.Any.

Comment: @Argenet - you're right but... maybe I'm wrong... but I usually avoid to suggest solutions that aren't strictly iso standard.

Comment: @max66 although there are some design differences, especially between boost::variant and std::variant, those std:: classes were inspired by their Boost predecessors. Though if you're on a modern compiler, they should be already there.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need a buffer (of size `max(sizeof(T1), sizeof(T2), sizeof(T3)...)`), placement new, and a enum variable to remember which object is currently in the buffer. It's called a "tagged union". Then you'll need to write member functions to safely control the lifetime of this artifially-inseminated object. Finally, you'll want to spend a few days untangling any alignment requirements.

But this is what `boost::variant` does so just use that. It'll be `std::variant` soon, too.

Answer (score -3):

You cannot. A struct is always the same size. When you create a struct, the compiler reserves space for each member variable in the struct and defines that as the struct's size. When your code asks the memory manager to allocate memory for the struct, it will always allocate the same amount of memory, regardless of whether all of the variables are used or not.

Your best bet is to convert your string to another type that can be used in a union, such as a fixed-size array of chars.

Comment: That would be going backwards.

Comment: The asker never had any requirements about using as little memory as possible